# Path not to be hardcoded

Tags: c#, path

I'm using this path in my code:

"C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + "\Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Addins\"

but I don't want it to be hardcoded. Is there a way I can get it by code, for example with the Path class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) and [`Environment.GetFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby.aspx).

```
string myDocuments = Environment.GetFolderPath
    (Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
string addins = Path.Combine(myDocuments, "Visual Studio 2005", "Addins");
```

EDIT: Pre-.NET 4, the last line would be:

```
string addins = Path.Combine(Path.Combine(myDocuments, "Visual Studio 2005"),
                             "Addins");
```

Comment: @Srcee - `Path.Combine(params string[])` is only in .NET 4, and you can't chain it like that, because it's returning a `string` not a `Path` object, and `string` doesn't have Combine.  If you can't move to .NET 4, [try this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/760641/721276)

Comment: I solved it. But, I work in VS 2005 (.Net 2.0), then why does my program work when Path.Combine is for .Net 4.0?

Comment: @Scree - `Path.Combine(string, string)` exists in .NET 1.1 and higher, I was referring to that specific overload of the method (there are also overloads for 2, 3, and 4 arguments) for .NET 4.0

Comment: OK :)
I have one more question.
Path.Combine(Path.Combine(myDocuments, "Visual Studio 2005"), "Addins") gives me C:\Users\John\Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Addins, but I want the string to have \ in the end:
@"C:\Users\John\Documents\Visual Studio 2005\Addins\"
How to make it on an elegant way (without + "\\")?

Comment: @Srcee: Why do you want it to have a backslash at the end? If you're going to combine it with another file name, just use `Path.Combine` again.

Answer (score 1):

This gets you to ...\Documents:

`Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)`

Comment: Just noticed Jon's post - Personal is an equivalent to MyDocuments, in case you were wondering.