# Alternative to UNC path string

Tags: powershell

I'm creating a script to access a shared network folder. Sample code looks like this:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param (
    [string]$SharedFolder,

    [ValidateScript({ Test-NetConnection $_ -InformationLevel Quiet })]
    [string]$Hostname
)

[string]$UNCPath = "\\" + $Hostname + "\" + $SharedFolder

# Do stuff
Get-ChildItem $UNCPath # OK
```

My question is about the `$UNCPath` variable. Is there a cleaner, better way to accessing the share? Gluing the path together as a string looks ugly.

Is there a better way to access a UNC path using PowerShell?

Comment: `"\\${Hostname}\${SharedFolder}"`?

Comment: You can write `[string]$UNCPath = "\\$Hostname\$SharedFolder"` if you prefer. There are more alternatives at [How do I use join-path to combine more than two strings into a file path?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25880122/1115360)

Comment: As a side note, you should avoid 'typing' your variables.  Unlike, say C#, PowerShell is designed to be weakly typed and placing the type in front of a variable doesn't always help with situations of mismatching which would be caught by Visual Studio.  In particular using `[string]` is particularly deceptive.  In your case, for example, these would be valid syntactically and would generate no error at runtime, but are likely to lead to problems later on:  `[string]$UNCPath = [DateTime]::Now`, `[string]$UNCPath = Get-ADUser -Filter {Name -like "*boxdog*"}`

Comment: @boxdog Can you elaborate on what the problems would be and how Visual Studio would help if the $UNCPath were untyped? It seems to me that if the language was designed to be weakly typed it wouldn't have been designed to include type specifiers.

Comment: @veefu In his example, strongly-typing the variable *should* throw errors if you try to store something that doesn't match the type in the variable.

Comment: @veefu, Visual Studio would help (for, say, c#) because trying to assign, say, an ADUser object to a string would generate an error at compile-time; here it doesn't, so the 'typing' is not helping at all.  Also, doing this `[string]$UNCPath` is not really setting `$UNCPath` as a string in the same way as in other languages.  It is really a hidden cast operation, which allows you to assign a string to the variable, or _anything that can be cast to a string_. Since everything in .NET can be a string, then anything can be assigned to that variable, defeating the purpose of setting the type.

Comment: @boxdog It seems like questionable advice to me. I prefer to provide typing, especially for function parameters. To each their own.