# Dot Slash and Backslashes in PowerShell Cross-Platform

Tags: powershell

I'm writing PowerShell scripts which call other PowerShell scripts with `& .\other\script.ps1` but the backslash `\` is, I assume, a Windows thing and I want my scripts to work cross-platform.

I've noticed that PowerShell in Windows does accept `& ./other/script.ps1` but that may be accidental. Is PowerShell ALWAYS gonna translate my backslashes to the host platform?

What is the best approach to handling path seperators cross-platform in PowerShell?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my experience Windows PowerShell is happy to accept either `\` or `/` as a path separator so one way to be cross-platform is to always use `/`.

Alternatively you can use the `Path` cmdlets to handle building paths for you, for example:

```
Join-Path -Path $Pwd -ChildPath (Join-Path -Path 'Other' -ChildPath 'script.ps1')
```

Or to get the path for a file in the current directory:

```
Resolve-Path test.txt
```

Path cmdlets:

```
~> get-command *-path* | Select Name

Name
----
Convert-Path
Join-Path
Resolve-Path
Split-Path
Test-Path
```

Comment: You'll find that it's still most common for people to use something like `[IO.Path]::Combine('.', 'other', 'script.ps1')` even though there's [new, convenience functionality added to `Join-Path` beginning with Powershell 6](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53745818/530545).

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough credit to add a comment to the accepted answer by @mark-wragg but I just want to point out I started using forward slashes only in cross-platform scripts etc and hit a problem with symbolic links.

As an example, run

```bsh
new-item -itemtype SymbolicLink -path TestScript8.ps1 -target ./TestScript.ps1
```

and you will not be able to open `TestScript8.ps1` in VS Code on Windows.