# How do I remove a "base" portion of a path?

Tags: powershell

I have a series of folders in a source directory that I need to recreate in another environment. The source folder look like this:

```
C:\temp\stuff\folder01\
C:\temp\stuff\folder02\
C:\temp\stuff\folder03\
C:\temp\stuff\folder02\dog
C:\temp\stuff\folder02\cat
```

I need to remove the base portion of the path - `C:\temp\stuff` - and grab the rest of t he path to concatenate with the destination base folder in order to create the folder structure somewhere else.

I have following script. The problem seems to be with the variable `$DIR`. `$DIR` never gets assigned the expected "current path minus the base path".

The variable `$tmp` is assigned something close to the expected folder name. It contains the folder name minus vowels, is split across multiple lines, and includes a bunch of leading whitespace. For example, a folder named `folder01` would look like the following:

```
f
ld
r01
```

Here's the PowerShell script:

```
$SOURCES_PATH = "C:\temp\stuff"
$DESTINATION_PATH = "/output001"

Get-ChildItem "$SOURCES_PATH" -Recurse -Directory |
Foreach-Object {

    $tmp = $_.FullName.split("$SOURCES_PATH/")

    $DIR = $_.FullName.split("$SOURCES_PATH/")[1]

    $destination = "$DESTINATION_PATH/$DIR"

    *** code omitted ***
}
```

I suspect the `$DIR` appears to be unassigned because the [1] element is whitespace but I'm don't know why there is whitespace and what's happening to the folder name.

What's going on and how do I fix this?

Comment: You could replace "C:\temp\stuff" with the destination base folder. Or, for more robustness, use [Path.Combine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25893843/1115360).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`String.Split("somestring")` will split on every occurrence of *any* of the characters in `"somestring"`, which is why you're seeing the paths being split into many more parts than you're expecting.

I'd suggest using `-replace '^base'` to remove the leading part of the path:

```bsh
$SOURCES_PATH = "C:\temp\stuff"
$DESTINATION_PATH = "/output001"

Get-ChildItem "$SOURCES_PATH" -Recurse -Directory |Foreach-Object {

    # This turns "C:\temp\stuff\folder01" into "\folder01"
    $relativePath = $_.FullName -replace "^$([regex]::Escape($SOURCES_PATH))"

    # This turns "\folder01" into "/folder01"
    $relativeWithForwardSlash = $relativePath.Replace('\','/')

    # Concatenate destination root and relative path
    $rootedByDestination = "${DESTINATION_DIR}${relativeWithForwardSlash}"

    # Create/Copy $rootedByDestination here
}
```

`-replace` is a regular expression operator, which is why I run `[regex]::Escape()` against the input path, to double-escape the backslashes :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider replacing the source path with an empty string.  Then you can either concat what's left onto destination path, or use `Path::Combine` to take care of the concatenation and any separator drama.

Source:

```
Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object {
    $destination = [System.IO.Path]::Combine($DESTINATION_PATH, $_.FullName.Replace($SOURCES_PATH, ''))
}
```